# Decrease Image downloading time with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http

This is piece of code is using to download images. Can somebody tell me how to optimize this code to decrease download time for each image?

```
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            currentRequestInProgress.remove(urlString);
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
            if(input != null){
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 6):

**Buffered streams** usually result in greatly improved performance:

```
input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

The buffer size is 8kb per default, tuning it may be an option (but not without measuring).

And, if you download multiple images: **parallelize it with multiple threads** (most of the time is consumed by I/O waits anyway), this usually improves performance by *factors*.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is tagged android. I thus suspect you have a **very** limited bandwidth. Your CPU waiting times don't really decrease when you try to squeeze more through the bandwith...

Comment: Good catch, from http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html : `The input and output streams returned by this class are not buffered. Most callers should wrap the returned streams with BufferedInputStream or BufferedOutputStream. Callers that do only bulk reads or writes may omit buffering.`

Answer (score 3):

#### Resources:

You should really use  try-with-resources:

```
URL url = new URL(urlstring);
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive","true");
try(HTTPUrlConnection connection = (HTTPUrlConnection) url.openConnection()){
    connection.setConnectTimeout(HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    try(InputStream input = connection.getInputStream()){
       return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
catch(MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

This code should do exactly the same. The finally becomes useless, as try-with-resources does the job for you. Keep in mind, your resources should implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, this is required to use try-with-resources.

As mentioned in some comments:

Try-with-resources works **only** as of Android 4.4.

furthermore, if `HTTPUrlConnection` does not implement `AutoCloseable` you will have to restructure the code like this:

```
HTTPUrlConnection connection
try{
    connection = (HTTPUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
    //[...]
} 
catch(MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
finally {
    if(connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: resource means ??

Comment: @MohitSharma about everything you `.open();` and `.close();`

Comment: This is a good advice in general but I don't think `HTTPUrlConnection` implements `Autocloseable`. There is a `connection.disconnect()` in the Op code, which is not in this code.

Comment: @MohitSharma - Android is based on Java6 - no try-with-resources.

Comment: @MohitSharma - actually, I [may be wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22303654/1305253) - but it is complicated.

Comment: @Marc-Andre that's why I mentioned it... I actually also doubt, it implements `AutoCloseable`, even though it probably really should...

Comment: Android till now support Java 1.5 only

Comment: Try with resources only works as of Android 4.4